# Ellipse patch equivalent to set_radius in the Circle Patch? Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, ellipse

To summarise the important bit:

I have a function which plots a circle on a matplotlib graph. Every time I recall the function I simply resize the circle (using set_radius), as It always needs to be in the same positon on the graph (in the centre). This way It doesn't get too messy

I want to do the same thing with an ellipse patch but this time be able to change the height, width and angle it is at. However I can't find any equivalent of set_radius

```
def Moment_Of_Inertia(self):
    """Plot the moment of Inertia ellipse, with the ratio factor """

    # my code to get ellipse/circle properties
    self.limitradius = findSBradius(self.RawImage,self.SBLimit)[0]
    MoIcall = mOinertia(self.RawImage,self.limitradius)
    self.ratio=MoIcall[0] #  get the axes ratio
    self.height=1
    Eigenvector = MoIcall[1]
    self.EllipseAngle np.degrees(np.arctanh((Eigenvector[1]/Eigenvector[0])))

    # This is the part I am not sure how to do
    self.MoIellipse.set(width=self.ratio*15)
    self.MoIellipse.set(height=self.height*15)
    self.MoIellipse.set(angle= self.EllipseAngle)

    # It works with a circle patch 
    self.circleLimit.set_radius(self.limitradius)
    self.circleLimit.set_visible(True)
    self.MoIellipse.set_visible(True)
    self.canvas.draw()
```

If my code is a bit out of context I am happy to explain more, I am trying to embed a matplotlib graph in a tkinter window. both patches are already initialized in the constructor and I just want to resize them.

Comment: What is `.MoIellipse`? Please read and understand [mcve].

Comment: It is the name of a patch I had already initialised in the constructor

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that the question is about the Ellipse from [`matplotlib.patches.Ellipse`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Ellipse.html).

This has attributes `width`, `height` and `angle`. You can set those attributes as

```
ellipse = matplotlib.patches.Ellipse((0,0),.5,.5)
ellipse.width = 1
ellipse.height = 2
ellipse.angle = 60
```

As for any other python object, you can also use `setattr`, like

```
setattr(ellipse,"width", 2)
```

Some complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.widgets

class sliderellipse(matplotlib.widgets.Slider):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.ellipse = kwargs.pop("ellipse", None)
        self.attr = kwargs.pop("attr", "width")
        matplotlib.widgets.Slider.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        self.on_changed(self.update_me)

    def update_me(self,val=None):
        setattr(self.ellipse,self.attr, val)
        self.ax.figure.canvas.draw_idle()

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, 
                         gridspec_kw={"height_ratios" : [1,.05,.05,.05],
                                      "hspace" : 0.5})
axes[0].axis([-1,1,-1,1])
axes[0].set_aspect("equal")
ellipse = matplotlib.patches.Ellipse((0,0),.5,.5)
axes[0].add_patch(ellipse)
labels = ["width", "height","angle"]
maxs = [2,2,360]
sl = []
for ax,lab,m in zip(axes[1:],labels,maxs):
    sl.append(sliderellipse(ax,lab,0,m,ellipse=ellipse,attr=lab))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your time, this is exactly what I am looking for